# How to add content inside view pager. I cant see content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to make profile view (see below).  [image]

Currently I have the view with profile photo and two tabs (Diary and Friends).

This is my activity layout which contains two tabs.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/base_background"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar">

        <include layout="@layout/dog_profile" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dog_header"
            android:background="@color/base_background"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This my diary fragment but I cant see anything within the diary fragment. Its probably on the top-left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_memories"
        style="@style/NoItemsStyle"
        android:text="@string/no_memories" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/FabStyle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have no idea what I should change that I could see the content inside the fragment.

In my activity I am setting the view pager like this

```
  ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new DogDiaryFragment(), tab1);
    adapter.addFragment(new DogFriendsFragment(), tab2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Add some java code or error if you are getting...

Comment: I have added the java code. I am not getting any error, I cant just see the content. I think I am setting the diary fragment wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing the relative layout to the linear layout with vertical orientation in the activity xml.